React Native - Style property not working in Bottom Sheet
I am setting up bottom sheets in my application. The issue is that I am not able to set the styles in bottom sheets.
Here is my code
      <BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        snapPoints={['25%']}
        index={-1}
        style={{backgroundColor:"#000228"}}
        enablePanDownToClose>

        {renderSheetContent()}

      </BottomSheet>

I followed everything from the documentation(https://ui.gorhom.dev/components/bottom-sheet/) but still facing this issue.
I want a solution to get rid of this problem.

If you want to change background style of bottom sheet then you can use backgroundStyle
